# How to restore OpenCart 3.0.3.2 database?

Tags: sql-server, database, phpmyadmin, opencart, opencart-3

I am using OpenCart version 3.0.3.2, and for some reasons i want to move my entire store from the server to localhost. I have downloaded all the store files from the server to my local folder and it is working well i can see my themes, extensions and all other modifications.
The only problem now is that the database is missing.

Things i have tried:

1. I have tried the traditional way to make backup and then restore from the admin dashboard. Admin->System->Maintenance->Backup/Restore. The backup is from the server store and then restore that file from localhost. After the loading of restoring SQL file it show me a successful restoring message but nothing change when i refresh the store!!.
2. I have entered the c-panel from the server and went to phpmyadmin page then export the database. After that the same things in localhost went to phpmyadmin page then import that file from the server. i have got successfully import message also but again nothing changes in the store, i cant see my products, store information or all other additions.
3. I have tried to clear the cache from the admin dashboard if it is some how related to this but nothing changes.

I am stuck now and i dont know how to get all the information of the store in my localhost if anyone can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check config.php file again and check the database name

Comment: Oh i am sorry i forget to say that  I have made all the changes in both files of config.php in root folder and admin folder. but still no changes in the store @jaypadaliya

Comment: Download your shop database via phpmyadmin UI. Create new database on your local server and upload downloaded database also via phpmyadmin. Change in your config files (both main and admin) path and connection credentials to your database.

Comment: Thank you very much @K.B. your solution work and solve my problem :)

Comment: @loay You can mark my comment as useful

Comment: In my case and opencart 3 copy of an existing installation cannot be transfered ok, even if all data in config files, htaccess, etc are ok, I have errors that state : Make sure you have refreshed Opencart Modifications. !